# Google chrome can not read and writes to its data directory

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[Unable to resolved this issue. I am trying to running a script by using selenium with chromedriver 117.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqlY1.png)

Tried with remvoing system key but its not working. Tried with all the solutios which are provided in internet but nothing is working.[x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PW6sM.png)

Comment: check permissions... it's unable to create that temp directory for the session.  The path and message is a little unusual though... include driver initialization code in your post.